# All my sons's browsers freeze on Facebook when doing status update

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, browser, freeze, facebook

When my son tries to update his status on Facebook the browsers (Safari and Chrome) freeze (spinning beachball of death). He has been doing a hard restart to stop it. As this is not a good practice on any computer, any suggestions as to what it is in Facebook's page that might cause this would help. This only happens on Facebook. I plan to have him duplicate the error when I am there so that I can check the Console messages to see if a process is showing an error, and also Activity Monitor so that I can see if something is maxing out his memory. However, any suggestions you might have will be appreciated.

He has done Safe Boot and repair permissions without resolution. I am suspicious that there may be a Daemon or other item needed by Facebook that is hanging up. I also think it couldn't hurt to run a full set of OnyX repair, cleaning routines.

iMac Intel Duo, 2 Gig memory, Snow Leopard 10.6.8, Browsers: Safari and Chrome latest versions

Comment: He's restarting the computer because the browser is frozen?

Comment: To rule out WebKit-related issues, please also try [Firefox](http://www.firefox.com).

Comment: My son's entire system eventually freezes. At first he can switch to other programs, but then they no longer respond. I was unable to use Activity Monitor and Console to diagnose the problems because they froze also.

Comment: He is planning on trying Firefox after he gets home. He presently does not have it on his system.

Comment: Sounds like it's Facebook's new look and feel. Winter Freeze...

Comment: Firefox froze also.